# What is the correct setting for GOPATH?

Tags: go

I was trying to follow a tutorial on using aws with go. When I gave the command "go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws", I still got failure to import. I was left wondering if the "go get" succeeded or not.

Following the guidance provided in the answers here, I updated my GOPATH variable and now the import succeeds.

Comment: Import the full package location: "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws". Then you can use the package aws.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportingRemote This might help

Comment: I gave the command "go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws" and it comleted silently, When i give the command "go run hello.go", I get "cannot find package. Did the command succeed or fail. I looked at the reference @Shubham Srivastava provided but did not understand it. What does "go mod init" do? Do I need a module path to use this package? Or any package?

Comment: go uses full url for libraries for example aws is available on github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws, so @AnnaNaden you need to do a import with full URL as import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go to  learn how packages work and how they are imported and read How to Write Go Code and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hello.go should start something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
)
```

See [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/17etrjba8BJ) in the playground. So when importing a [remote module](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportingRemote) use the full path in the import statement.

Re another question you asked in the comments (and I mentioned in comments to another of your questions) - `go mod init` initialises a module. See [this article](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) for information. When using modules, GOPATH is no longer used for resolving imports (see [this article](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules)). So basically `GOPATH`is the old way of doing things; go modules is the new way (it solves a lot of issues but having the two approaches can be confusing to someone new to the language because some tutorials assume GOPATH and others use modules).

For completeness you have other questions about environmental variables. I think this may be due to a misunderstanding about how these work. When you enter `export GOPATH=XXX` in a terminal session that will update the environment within that session (that is that terminal window only; it will not have any impact on any other sessions you have open, including vscode). If you want to set a system wide environmental variable then you need to update a configuration file (often `~/.bashrc` but this depends upon your OS see [this article](https://opensource.com/article/19/8/what-are-environment-variables) for info). After doing that restart the applications (or ideally youre PC) to pick up the new setting.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws`; `go` tool will download the package into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws` directory.

That is why you need to import package by its full name (which is same as path to files under `$GOPATH/src` directory:

```golang
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
```

You can find more about how source code is organized under `GOPATH` and how imports work [here](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html) and specifically about remote (github) imports [here](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html#remote).

NOTE: `GOPATH` resolution works only when your project doesn't use modules (you don't have `go.mod` file). If you're following a tutorial and it doesn't mention use of modules above should work fine.